# one pivot chart can we use two different slicer or data. to display dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

one pivot chart can we use (dynamically- it means when we are using 1st slicer then pi chart will show another output, and when select another 2nd slicer pi chart will show another view. on the same chart)two different slicer or data. to display dynamically.

1. i have tried on two different pi chart, but i want to adjust the pi (single pi chart dynamically)chart at same area.

i have not use any code but want to solve the problem using vba.

one pivot chart can we use (dynamically- it means when we are using 1st slicer then pi chart will show another output, and when select another 2nd slicer pi chart will show another view. on the same chart)two different slicer or data. to display dynamically.

Comment: Coudl you show us some picture, an example input, and an expected output please?

Comment: one pivot chart is already connected with a slicer and perfectly working (bifurcating row wise data in PI chart), i just want to add with the display the same chart by using another slicer (which should be bifurcating the data in column wise),

Comment: Okay... so could you show us some picture, an example input, and an expected output please?

Comment: i think in this application i am not able to paste screen shot, if any other way please advice.

Comment: Well then create an excel which is like the one you cannot post a screenshot of